# How to add load test with multiple user with auth header value in Jemeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I am came to this step, but always getting first users request in my API
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parameterize your HTTP Header Manager somehow, depending on where and how you can get these headers it might be:

1. Storing headers in the CSV file and using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each user would have its own header
2. [Getting authorization data from the database](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter) using JDBC test elements
3. Calculating the header using relevant [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
4. Extracting headers from the previous response where you perform login or open the login page, this is called [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a csv file that contains your users credentials

users1, password1
users2, password2
....

then add a config Element as CSV Data and make the path to your csv file.

you can follow this guide
https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/how-to-use-csv-file-for-login-multiple-users-through-jmeter/

Comment: still I am not able to fire multiple req at single time, it is going one-by-one. CSV trick works for me. thanx